# Trying to extract data from MYSQL in excel sheet and getting runtime error 2147467259 (80004005)

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

I'm learning to extract data from MYSQL to excel, as an attempt using the below code to extract data from a MYSQL table, i'm getting **runtime error 2147467259 (80004005)**..

```
Sub connect()
Dim Password As String
Dim sqlstr As String
Dim Server_Name As String
Dim User_ID As String
Dim Database_Name As String
Dim table_name As String
 
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Server_Name = "20.20.10.20"
Database_Name = "test"
User_ID = "user1"
Password = "abcd!7B3"
table_name = "tbl_master"
 
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};Server=" & _
        Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
        ";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"
 
sqlstr = "SELECT * FROM table1;"
rs.Open sqlstr, cn, adopenstatic
 
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
cn.Close
MsgBox "DONE!" End sub
```

[image]

why i'm getting this error, am i mising anything, can anyone guide me?

Comment: Have you tried adding with reference to ADO, so you can say dim c as new adodb.connection.

Comment: MySQL driver is installed?

Comment: Yes MYSQL driver installed

Comment: Yes @Nathan_Sav getting the same error

Comment: What version of ADO did you select?

Comment: ADO 2.8 version